Плавное перемещение меток в yandex-maps-api
Необходимо реализовать следующий функционал:

Есть набор координат на карте
Есть созданный geo-object(placemark)
Необходимо перемещать маркер от первой точки до последней

Есть ли в yandex-maps-js-api такой функционал, чтобы перемещение было плавным, а не "прыжками" от координаты к координате?
Как пример есть такое же поведение для google maps (https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/issues/700)
Но в случае я Яндекс картами такой подход не работает
